# password built in an app for restricted download?

Tags: applications, security, password, privacy

I have built an app. It's a magazine and a few brochures with rich content. I will upload it as a multi issue app. Once it's approved and available in the iTunes app store, I would like it to be available only to those who have a password to download it. But I'm not sure that it's possible to do this. I hope my question is now clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Technically, a lot of things are possible, but your question is lacking important detail right now. Is this a question about how to develop such an application (which would make stackexchange.com), is it a question about whether the Mac or iOS App Store accept such apps (then we might be the right place), is it not even an OSX/iOS app (then we are definitively *not* the right place) or something completely else? You can edit the question using the edit link at the bottom to add details if necessary.

Comment: This question can now be answered, and I've voted to reopen.

Comment: It is much clearer now, thank you.  So why would you use App Store (a public place) but than make it only available to password users?. Would not the Google drive be better for that?

Comment: That's my client's choice. He wants to put his material in an app for his team.

Comment: I am not sure you can do the only password on the App Store. Maybe using some Price/Coupon would work. ppl with coupon get it for free.

Comment: Looks like the solution is to create an app that requires login to open.

Comment: There are enterprise developer accounts which allow in-house distribution (then it won't be in the app store but you have all the same native possibilities). You can't set a password to restrict downloads from the App Store. If you want it on the App Store but have the material restricted, create a login system for your app.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a very hard time getting the app approved is my guess, but you can always try.

It's not clear why you aren't using the newsstand functionality - and that will certainly be on the reviewer's mind when they are deciding if the app store needs another app added to the pile.

Technically, you can offer apps that require payment - see HBO Go, various major league baseball apps, but they all either have a free period to explore the paid content or significant free capabilities to justify being available on the app store.

Unless you can show huge value to some people, you'll be facing a hard sell once it's time to get it past review. If you can, start by submitting a test app to the beta testing review using Test Flight. That will only cost you $100 and the time to develop the initial version of the app.

From there you will have a dialog with the review team to judge if or how they will respond to your specific app.

All the above goes out the window if you are selling the app B2B and your purchasers are only [VPP businesses](https://vpp.itunes.apple.com/). Then you have a great business model and chance for success selling a [custom business app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).